# accessing object values that are inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm hoping someone can help with what is likely a simple answer - but I'm ready to bash my head against the wall....again.

I have a function which makes a JSON call to an API, and then pushes the results into an array.   The function appears to work just fine as my console.log is showing that the array is populated correctly.

I'm struggling with how to access the values of the modified twichResult object (after the function has run), so that I can do 'stuff' with it. e.g. display the value of the 'status' property onscreen etc...   I give some examples of what I've tried in the in the large commented out section.

I'd really appreciate some intelligence weighing in on this as I've exhausted my resources.  Thanks in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function()  {

  var twitchResult = {results:[]};
  var channel = { logo:"", display_name:"", status:"", url:"" };
  var finalUrl = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp?callback=?"
  
  getTwitchers (finalUrl, "freecodecamp");
  console.log(twitchResult);

  //  How do I access the individual values in the object TwitchResult?  
  //  I get "undefined" in the console if I try to access the object's property values
  //  I've tried every way I can think of to get 'into' the returned object :
  //  console.log(twitchResult.results);
  //  console.log(twitchResult["results"])
  //  console.log(twitchResult.results.status)
  //  console.log(twitchResult[0])
  //  console.log(twitchResult[0][0])
  //  etc etc
   
  function getTwitchers (url, item) {

   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
   
   var obj = data.stream;
          
      // Check if the object is not valid using (obj == null) which is shorthand for both null and undefined
      if (obj == null) {
       if (obj === undefined) {
           channel.display_name = item;
           channel.status = "closed";
           console.log ("this is undefined");
       }
       else {
           channel.display_name = item;              
           channel.status = "offline";
           console.log("this is null");
       }
      }
      else {
       channel.logo =  obj.channel.logo;
    channel.display_name =  obj.channel.display_name;
       channel.status =  obj.channel.status;
       channel.url =  obj.channel.url; 
       console.log("valid entry");          
      }

            twitchResult["results"].push(channel);

//          twitchResult.results.push(channel);
//      console.log(twitchResult);  
  
   });
  }
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getJSON is making an ajax-request. You must handle this request from within the request handler. When getTwichers returns, twichResults is not yet set.

There are methods to delay Program execution, until twichResults is done, but You should not think of using them, since they would delay program execution. The idea of ajax is to execute things asynchronously, without disturbing the rest of the execution flow. If the code You want to execute depends on the json, then You should add it to the handle in $.getJSON. Just write a new function (e.g. continue_execution(twichResult)) and invoke it right after twitchResult["results"].push(channel);. Just don't do anything after getTwitchers(...).

By the way: It is a good habit to define functions, before they are used, because it follows the flow the human eye reads the code and there are programming languages, which depend on this style of declaring function.

If this is unclear to You, then add a comment.

Comment: Thanks. So any handling/manipulating of the data that the getJSON request makes  needs to happen within:  $.getJSON(url, function(data){ }  ?
Is there any way in the known universe to suspend the return of getTwitchers until all the JSON data is in (and twichResults is therefore set) ?

Comment: @Zander: I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of defining and then calling function - I am keen to learn good, clean habits.   Also, it's good to know that I shouldn't be looking for program execution delay methods.  I appreciate your time on answering my questions!

Comment: @Zander: happy to help You. Don't forget to accept the answer :) .